# QSortFilterProxyModel sort multiple columns

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, sorting, model

I am trying to implement a table that is sortable on more than one column. Qt's QSortFilterProxyModel only supports sorting on one column (at least in Qt 4.6.2).

I've found [this solution](https://github.com/dimkanovikov/MultisortTableView) by dimkanovikov on github, but it lacks dynamic updating on added rows. What I mean by this, is that the model is changed and the beginInsertRows(), beginRemoveRows(), their corresponding end..-methods and the dataChanged() signals are emitted. Ideally I would like to only these rows to be updated, but the model should at least react to such changes.

There's another FAQ item on Qt's site that sorts a QTableWidget, but it lacks dynamic updating, too.

I am new to Qt and I'd like to get some pointers on how I should go about this.

Comment: As a side note: If you sort column B and then column A, all rows with the same value in A should be sorted by B. That kind of allows for reverse sorting, i.e. if you want to sort for A, then B, then C, you have to actually sort the table by C, then B, then A

Comment: Reverse sorting may work faster then the solution I went with, but then you would have to reimplement ``void QAbstractItemModel::sort ( int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder )`` and is probably more complicated to implement then what I did.

Comment: What I described requires no extra implementation, it's Qt's default behaviour. It's just if you click column B, then column A in a standard QTableView (granted sorting is enabled for those columns), and there are rows which have the same A value but different B values, those B values will be sorted as well. Your own solution will probably be better for your case though

Comment: @Tim Meyer:my experience contradicts the assumption. Sorting column B, then A, introduces gaps in B. Seems that the default sorting is *not* stable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's one slightly inelegant solution, that is always used to sort multiple columns.

You have to subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` and reimplement `bool lessThan(const QModelIndex &rLeft, const QModelIndex &rRight) const`. Instead of only comparing between the two given indices, check all the columns:

```
int const left_row  = rLeft.row();
int const right_row = rRight.row();

int const num_columns = sourceModel()->columnCount();
for(int compared_column = rLeft.column(); compared_column<num_columns; ++compared_column) {
    QModelIndex const left_idx = sourceModel()->index(left_row, compared_column, QModelIndex());
    QModelIndex const right_idx = sourceModel()->index(right_row, compared_column, QModelIndex());

    QString const leftData = sourceModel()->data(left_idx).toString();
    QString const rightData = sourceModel()->data(right_idx).toString();

    int const compare = QString::localeAwareCompare(leftData, rightData);
    if(compare!=0) {
        return compare<0;
    }
}

return false;
```

Then you can call `sort(0)` on your `QSortFilterProxyModel` subclass and it will sort all the columns. Also don't forget to call `setDynamicSortFilter(true)` when you want the sorted rows to be dynamically resorted when the model data changes.

To support sorting on arbitrary columns in ascending or descending order, you would have to keep this info in a `QList` and compare accordingly when `lessThan` is called. In the list you would have the columns in order of their priority and do the comparisons in the same order. You should also sort the other "inactive" columns in some predefined order, otherwise they will not be sorted by default.

Comment: This technique can even be safely applied to a `QTableWidget`. You just have to subclass `QTableWidgetItem` and override `__lt__` method

Comment: Please note the above implementation is ignoring the sortRole. A good implementation would use the sortRole set on the proxy model to query the data to compare. Also note that converting to strings may not be the best way to compare values. If a column contains dates or numbers, comparing based on strings will cause unnatural sort orders.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. It would be interesting to see how the default implementation does this. I guess you could use the QVariant::operator<, but I don't know how well that works with different types.

Also you could probably add the sortRole to the data() call without problems.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the sorting role of the `QSortFilterProxyModel` to something different then the default `Qt::DisplayRole` with`setSortRole(Qt::UserRole)`. Then, in your model's `data()` method return a proper sort key if it gets called with the role `Qt::UserRole`, e.g. by concatenating the strings of the involved columns.